# How to check if a custom error message is thrown by abort() in Flask?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, error-handling, jinja2, wsgi

I'm creating a simple web app using Flask. For some views, I'm throwing a 403 error if certain conditions are not matched:

```
@admin.route("/employees/assign/<int:id>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def assign_employee(id):
    """Assign a department and a role to an employee."""
    check_admin()

    employee = Employee.query.get_or_404(id)

    if employee.is_admin:
        abort(403,f"You're not permitted to edit {employee.first_name}'s role and department.")

    do_something()
    return render_template(a_template)
```

To handle those errors, I've also added error handlers in my main init file.

```
@app.errorhandler(403)
def fordbidden(error):
    return (
        render_template(
            "errors/403.html", title="Forbidden", error_message=error.description
        ),
        403,
    )
```

Finally, I'm displaying the error description in my Jinja template:

```
<div style="text-align: center">
    <h1> 403 Error </h1>
    {% if error_message %}
        <h3> {{error_message}} </h3>
    {% else %}
        <h3>You're not authorised to access this ressource.</h3>
    {% endif %}
    <hr class="intro-divider">
    <a href="{{ url_for('home.homepage') }}" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
        Home
    </a>
</div>
```

What I'd like to do is to display the custom error message **if and only if** there's one, otherwise to use the standard message defined in my template. However, it seems that my `{% if error_message %}` will always be true because the error is always passing a message by default.

Is there a way to check for the presence of a custom error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in default filter of jinja2:

You can replace the if-else structure with the following:

```
<h3>{{error_message|default(“You're not authorised to access this resource.“‚true)}}</h3>
```